# Why is $ \mathbb{P}\left(| \int_X f_n(\cdot, x) \mathbb{1}_{| f_n(\cdot, x)| < M} d\nu(x)|\geq \epsilon \right) = 0. $

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, analysis, measure-theory

> Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \nu)$ be a measured space where $\nu$ is a
> finite (positive) measure and let $(\Omega, \mathcal{B}, \mathbb{P})$
> be a probabilized space. We consider a sequence of functions
> $\left(f_n\right)_{n \in \mathbf{N}}$ defined on $\Omega \times X$ and
> with values in $\mathbb{R}$. We suppose that
>
> - For all $n \in \mathbb{N}, f_n$ is $(\mathcal{B} \times \mathcal{A})$-measurable;
> - there exists $\delta>0$ for which $ \int_X\left|f_n(\cdot, x)\right|^{1+\delta} d \nu(x)$ is bounded in probability, i.e., for
>   any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ for which
>   $\int_X\left|f_n(\cdot, x)\right|^{1+\delta} d \nu(x)$ is bounded in
>   probability, i.e., for any $\varepsilon>0$,
> - there exists $\delta>0$ for which ${ }^2 \int_X\left|f_n(\cdot, x)\right|^{1+\delta} d \nu(x)$ is bounded in probability, i.e., for
>   any $\varepsilon>0$, there exist $C_{\varepsilon}>0$ and
>   $N_{\varepsilon} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for any integer $n \geq N_{\varepsilon}$, $$\mathbb{P}\left(\int_X\left|f_n(\cdot,
>   > x)\right|^{1+\delta} \geq C_{\varepsilon}\right) \leq \varepsilon $$
> - For almost all $x \in X, \left(f_n(\cdot, x)\right)$ converges in probability to $0 .$

I have a only one little question (maybe it's a silly one), why do we have that
$$ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, 
\mathbb{P}\left(| \int_X f_n(\cdot, x) \mathbb{1}_{| f_n(\cdot, x)| < M} d\nu(x)|\geq \epsilon \right) = 0.
$$
To explain it I computed

\begin{align} 
\epsilon \leq| \int_X f_n(\cdot, x) \mathbb{1}_{| f_n(\cdot, x)| < M} d\nu(x)| &\leq \int_X | f_n(\cdot, x) | \mathbb{1}_{| f_n(\cdot, x)| < M} d\nu(x) \\
&\leq \epsilon \int_X d\nu(x) \\
&\leq \epsilon \nu(X).
\end{align}
Is it because we can take $\epsilon$ arbitrary small, so that both sides are close to zero. Thus by squeeze theorem it is zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is just by the Dominated Convergence Theorem because the following sequence of functions is uniformly bounded:

$$ | f_n(\cdot, x) 1_{\left|f_n(\cdot, x)\right|<M} | \leq M$$

and because by assumption $f_n(\cdot, x) \rightarrow 0$ in probability then there exists a version of the Dominated Convergence Theorem that makes use of the Almost Sure Representation Theorem for which is enough to have convergence in probability (not needed a.s. convergence). Thus I would say for every $n$ big enough:

$$\left|\int_X f_n(\cdot, x) 1_{\left|f_n(\cdot, x)\right|<M} d \nu(x)\right|  
 \leq \int_X \left| f_n(\cdot, x) 1_{\left|f_n(\cdot, x)\right|<M}\right| d \nu(x) < \epsilon$$